# How to use find with an associated model and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a have_and_belong_to_many relationship between a Resources model and ResourceType model.

I am trying to find all resources that are joined by a ResourceType with the :name NOT equal to "event".

I have it working so that I can find Resources with ResourceType.names equal to "event" like this:

```
Resource.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :include => :resource_types, :conditions => {:resource_types => {:name => 'event'}})
```

but I want to find everything else with :name != 'event'.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
Resource.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :include => :resource_types, :conditions => ['resource_types.name != ?', 'event'])
```